# Increasing margins of facet_grid text

Tags: r, ggplot2, margins

I'm trying to make a `facet_grid` plot as shown in the example below. One of the names of the facets is too long to be displayed correctly, so it gets cut off.

I tried adding a margin around the text to display the full facet name correctly. However, the `margin` option in `element_text` only allows me to add horizontal margins - the height of the text fields seems to be fixed. Is there a way I can add vertical margins as well?

```
library (ggplot2)    

x <- mtcars
x$cyl <- as.factor (x$cyl)
levels (x$cyl) <- c ("a", "b", "this is a very very long name")

ggplot (x, aes (x = mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point () +
  facet_grid (cyl ~ .) +
  theme (strip.text = element_text (margin = margin (30, 5, 30, 5))) # This line should increase the margins
```

Version info: R 4.0.3, ggplot2 3.3.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the facet panels all need to be the same size. If you want to keep the overall plot the same size *and* the text the same size, you simply have run out of room to play with. You can't fit a quart in a pint jug.

I think the most elegant solution is to wrap the text:

```r
levels(x$cyl) <- stringr::str_wrap(levels(x$cyl), width = 20)

ggplot (x, aes (x = mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point () +
  facet_grid (cyl ~ .) +
  theme (strip.text = element_text (margin = margin (30, 5, 30, 5)))
```

[image]

If this doesn't work for you, the other options the common sense ones: facet in the x direction instead of the y direction, or shorten your labels, or shrink the text or increase the resolution of the plot.

---

**EDIT**

If you are prepared to have different sizes of facet, you could build the plot as a `ggplotGrob`, then find the panel whose height you wish to change and specify that as a proportion of the total plot height using "npc" units, like this:

```r
p <- ggplot (x, aes (x = mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point () +
  facet_grid (cyl ~ .) +
  theme (strip.text = element_text (margin = margin (30, 5, 30, 5))) 

b <- ggplotGrob(p)
b$heights[11] <- unit(0.4, "npc")
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(b)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I like the line break idea, but unfortunately that's not really an option in my use case. Same for the other options, I'm afraid.

What I'm looking for is really a way to force the third panel to have a specified minimum height.

Comment: @karpfen but that's my point. The panels all have to be the same height. The largest any of them can be is one-third the height of your plot. If you set a minimum height for one, you are setting it for all three. If three times the minimum height is larger than the space you have available, then you just don't have enough space. Are you wanting to change the relative heights of the three panels? If not, then what you are asking for is logically impossible when you think about it.

Comment: Oh, I don't mind if they are spaced irregularly. I'd be happy with something that looks like this, too: `facet_grid (cyl ~ ., scales = "free", space = "free_y")`. Sorry about being unclear!

Comment: @karpfen ah, that's different. See my update for how to achieve this. I don't think it can be done directly in ggplot, but you can adjust the grid object it produces to get the desired result

Answer (score 0):

One option could be adding space in the text:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Code
levels (x$cyl) <- c ("a", "b", "this is a very\n very long name")
#Plot
ggplot (x, aes (x = mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point () +
  facet_grid (cyl ~ .) +
  theme (strip.text = element_text(size=9, lineheight=1.5))
```

Output:

[image]